# Problem with adding event code to newly created sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with adding an event code to a newly created sheet.

The problem seems to only occur right after I open the Excel workbook.
I use

```
Dim codemod As Object
codemod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Sheet4").CodeName).CodeModule
```

to add the code to the created sheet module but when I try to run this code right after opening the Excel workbook it gives me an error: run-time error '9' Subscript out of range. The debug points to the codemod line.

The weird part is that this error does not come up again when I change the code just a tiny bit and then change it back to the original state. After I do this the code runs as it should i.e. inserts code to the newly created sheet.

Anyone got any idea what may be the problem?

There is not much else to the code except inserting the lines but that does not seem to be the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you change to the code event "a tiny bit" that made it work ?

Comment: that error sounds like the sheets don't load as fast as the code runs. Place a delay prior to running the code on open. I ran into this problem and sometimes it still occurs.

Comment: That tiny bit is like if I comment the line out and then uncomment right away. So basically I do nothing.

I have tried delaying the run between the sheet creating and adding the codemodule for five seconds and it did not help.

Comment: What about Thisworkbook. instead of ActiveWorkbook.

Answer (score 0):

(This is my first action on S.O. so please don't shout at me when I'm doing things wrong.)

Did you concider preparing a workbook + sheet with the desired event code (Test1.xls-Sheet1). Then, in the target workbook (Test2.xls), copy that prepared sheet. The code in the target workbook would look like

```
Sub Demo1()
  Workbooks.Open "Test1.xls"
  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Test2.xls"). _
     Sheets(Workbooks("Test2.xls").Worksheets.Count)
  Workbooks("Test2.xls").Activate
End Sub
```

This obviously is a workaround but it works instantly.

A second option could be to prepare the 'workbook-with-one-sheet' and save it as a (sheet) template in D:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART. In that case the code can be

```
Sub Demo2()
  Sheets.Add Type:="Test1"
End Sub
```